# How to change url so that it looks like cleanUrl in code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to change the url that reads

http://my_blog.com/user/getdetails?userid=5

to

http://my_blog.com/user/5

Where **user** is controller, **getdetails** is method and **5** is userid

How can i achieve this?

I did the following way

i changed **getdetails** to **index** so that i dont need to mention **getdetails** again

```
class user extends CI_Controller {

    function index()
    {
      $userid = $_GET['userid'];
      $this->load->model('data_model');
      $result=$this->data_model->data($userid);
    }
}
```

After the change it will now look like 
http://my_blog.com/user?userid=5

**UPDATE**

Is it possible to do the following in route.php 
`$route['bloop/(:num)'] = "foldername/bloop/index/$1";`
Where foldername is some folder on my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation about URI routing :

> http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

You have to do two things :

First, define a route in `application/config/routes.php` :

```
$route['user/(:num)'] = "user/index/$1";
```

And give your action method a parameter as explained **[here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#passinguri)** :

```
class user extends CI_Controller {

    function index($id)
    {
      $userid = $id;
      $this->load->model('data_model');
      $result=$this->data_model->data($userid);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does changing $route in config effects other controllers? I want this type of functionality to only user controller but not to others?

Comment: Yes it will effects every single controller, you don't have the choice. But if you make sure your route starts with `user/`, it will only effects the user controller. If you decide then to have i.e. `user/test` for another controller, you can set `$route['user/test'] = 'othercontroller/test';`. The order of the routes defined is important.

Comment: Great, here is the order in route.php 1. $route['defaultcontroller']="videos"; 2.$route['user/:num']="user"; 
Is that right?

Comment: As @Brewal said, the order of routes defined is important. So make your last route what you want to be your default. Then any exceptions, including your 404 route, will go before that.

Comment: It isn't working, the value passed is unable to reach to the function in that class. And the route precedence is 
1. $route['user/:num'] = "user";
2.$route['404_override'] = '';
3.$route['default_controller'] = "admin/videos";  
What might be the cause?

Comment: I mean the function is not getting the parameter value i.e index($id) is empty

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the parameter in the route, and try to add parenthesis : `$route['user/(:num)'] = "user/$1";`

Comment: Can you expplain what is "user/$1" should we hardcode the value to 1 or any purpose?

Comment: Got it it should be $route['user/(:num)']="user/index/$1"

Thank you very much mate. for the link and valuable solution

Comment: the `$1` is to catch the first occurence of a parameter in the string `user/(:num)`. If you had `$route['user-(:num)/(:any)'] = "user/$2/$1`, and the method : `index($theAnyParameter, $theNumParameter) {}`, then you see you can have an url like `user-5/more`

Comment: Thank, you have a nice code ! (I would appreciate an accepted answer and an upvote !)

Comment: Is it possible to do the following in route.php $route['bloop/(:num)'] = "foldername/bloop/index/$1";  ?

Comment: I think you always have to keep this : "controllername/actionname/param1/param2/...". Here codeigniter will look for the "foldername" controller and "bloop" action.

Answer (score 1):

```
class user extends CI_Controller {

    function index($id)
    {
      $userid = $id;
      $this->load->model('data_model');
      $result=$this->data_model->data($userid);
    }
}
```

the code above makes the url looks like http://my_blog.com/user/5

but  you do not need to always do that in your index function you can do like below

```
class user extends CI_Controller {

   function index($id)
   {
      $userid = $id; 
      //
      //do some other things
      //
      $this->getdetails($userid);  //default handle
   }

   function getdetails ($userid )
   {
     $this->load->model('data_model');
     $result=$this->data_model->data($userid);
   }
}
```

the url can be both
http://my_blog.com/user/5 and http://my_blog.com/user/getdetails/5

Comment: And then you have duplicate content issue ?

Comment: does not matter, if you wish index function can do some other things this mey be a good choice